# I2S boot overlays configurations for RPI CM4

Tags: raspbian, compute-module, microphone, i2s, speakers

I am trying to install a mono or stereo I2S microphones to a Raspberry Pi CM4 Board.
I am getting some reference links for configurations but they are suggested to work on the older version of the RPI Boards.

[Old Kernel Install Method](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-and-test)

Is there any solution to enable I2S overlays on the RPI CM4 Board?

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-test

Comment: @goldilocks: I have tried this already. but as I said, I would like to know how can I configure boot overlay for the I2S port as per my device/requirment. Do you have any solution regarding this?

Comment: You might want to edit this by making that clear then, because you say the "reference links" you found "work on the older version", when pretty much right on the same page there is the newer version which I linked.   So the existence of the "old method"  is irrelevant to the question about an overlay, yet it is what you have spent half your words on...